# Komodo Edit: How to use Tabs and Carriage Returns in Find/Replace?

Tags: tabs, find, find-and-replace, carriage-return, komodo-edit

In **NoteTab Pro**, I could use tabs and returns in the find and replace dialogs by using **^t** and **^p**.

Now I have switched to **Komodo Edit** which is much more powerful, and I can't find any way to search for these characters.

For the moment, I am not using regular expressions -- just regular find and replace.

Is there an equivalent functionality to, for example, replace all **,returns** with **;returns**? Or all **tabtab"** with **tab'**?

If it's necessary, I can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\t` for tabs and `\n` for end of line characters (if on Windows that may need to be `\r\n` for end of line if the file in question is using DOS/Windows-style end of line characters).

Note as well, if you just want to match something at the end of a line **but not match the end of line character itself** you can use `$`.

Comment: Don't know how I missed your answer.